# Setcapture causing PtInRect to malfunction?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

For some reason, using the SetCapture function, causes the PtInRect() function to not work!

Here's some code:

```
POINT curmouse;
RECT testrect = {0, 0, 200, 200};

WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
if (MK_LBUTTONDOWN == true)
SetCapture(hWnd);
break;

WM_MOUSEMOVE:
curmouse.x = LOWORD(lParam);
curmouse.y = HIWORD(lParam);

WM_LBUTTONUP:
if (PtInRect(&testrect , curmouse))
//Draw Image
```

Please Note: I did not make a call to release capture on WM_LBUTTONUP. In fact, releasecapture is never called!

If I do not call setcapture, then ptinrect works as intended on mouse release.

Can someone please tell me how to get ptinrect to work with setcapture() being called?

**Most importantly, there are two seperate windows in this program. The first window is named bg_window, the second, other_window.**

Comment: Which window are you capturing the mouse to? The coordinates you get when the mouse is captured will be relative to the client area of the window that has captured it.

Answer (score 2):

You're only initialising `curmouse` on `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, not `WM_LBUTTONUP` - so the values in there when you actually get a button up will be random.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason not to use the cursor coordinates passed in the LPARAM to [WM_LBUTTONUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Here's the thing. When SetCapture() is not called, the values assigned to curmouse in WM_MOUSEMOVE work, that is to say, the program recognizes that the mouse was in fact released in the rect (so the values in curmouse on WM_LBUTTONUP are not random). However, when SetCapture() is called, the program no longer recognizes that the mouse is in the rect.

Comment: @ Mark, when SetCapture() is called, the mouse coords sent to the lParam on WM_LBUTTONUP also, do not work.

Comment: @JamesDiaz Please be more specific what you mean by "do not work". What values do you expect, and what values are you getting?

Comment: They may not or may not actually be "random" values, but Jonathan's answer is still correct. You're not initializing `curmouse` for all of the messages you handle. That's absolutely required. Querying an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. It might *appear* to work, but you'll get strange behavior, Which is, um, sort of exactly what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

SetCapture() restricts the mouse messages to the window of which you passed the handle. Unless you call a ReleaseCapture() the mouse messages on the other window cannot be interpreted.Using SetCapture() and never calling ReleaseCapture() is not a good coding practice.

If your rect is in the other window the PtInrect is not going to work fine.
Also If you want to know whether the user clicked in the rect region you can use the mouse point you got during the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message.